# Converting JSON to List

Tags: c#, json

I am stuck in a step that I am sure should work. I have a method (in a separate class) that should return a List as its value after processing the JSON. I am going to paste the code skipping the JSON configuration stuff:

```
    public static dynamic CustInformation(string Identifier)
    {

  //SKIPPED JSON CONFIG STUFF (IT'S WORKING CORRECTLY)

        var result = "";
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        dynamic d;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.RootObject>>(result);
 }
```

The model was generated using C# to Json converter:

```
public class Record
{

    public string idIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string KnowName1 { get; set; }
    public string KnowAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string KnowRelation1 { get; set; }
    public string KnowPhone1 { get; set; }
    public string KnowName2 { get; set; }
    public string KnowAddress2 { get; set; }
    //.....skipped other variables

}


public class RootObject
{
    public List<Record> record { get; set; }
}
```

And I am calling the method like this:

```
 var model = Classes.EndPoint.CustInformation(identifier);
```

Yet I am getting this error everytime:

```
 Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type      'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
  To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change 
 the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
 Path 'record', line 1, position 10.
```

EDIT: JSON

```
  {
   "record": [
    {
      Identifier": "DQRJO1Q0IQRS",
      "KnowName1": "",
      "KnowAddress1": "",
      "KnowRelation1": "",
      "KnowPhone1": "",
      "KnowName2": "",
      "KnowAddress2": "",
      //.....MORE STYFF
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: the error's pretty clear: it's expecting a json array, and you're not providing that. what IS the json that you're feeding into the call?

Comment: You are serializing a root object that contains a list of Record objects. But you're deserializing a list of root objects that contains a list of record objects. You need to make sure you're serializing and deserializing to the same type.

Comment: Posted the JSON Marc, it should "line up"

Comment: Hi mason. I don't exactly get what you are saying; basically what I am doing is the same thing I've done before for converting the JSON to a DataTable. Its basically the same setup I had. As soon as I get the JSON from the API I deserialize it into RootObject, which has record. I am definitely missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, and like the error message clearly states, you're trying to deserialize into a list of root objects, but your JSON is only one root object, not an array.

Here's what your C# should be.

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.RootObject>(result);
```

Comment: OOOOH!!!! Now I get it! Thanks a lot Mason, really appreciated. It was just in front of me >_<!